# boot-repair Fails due to bad substitution in gui-actions.sh

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, nvme

My GRUB setup got messed up and I am trying to use `boot-repair` with live version of Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm getting an error that I have not seen before and can't figure out a proper way to fix it. Googling for the exact error or "boot-repair bad substitution issue" does not return anything `boot-repair` related.

After running either recommended repair or advanced repair, I get the `bad substitution` error in the log file and boot repair hangs (progress bar running forever).

```
...
SET@pulsatewindow.show()
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
SET@_label0.set_text('''Applying changes. This may require several minutes...''')
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
The settings chosen by the user will purge (in order to unsign) and reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  disable-internet-check nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file rename-ms-efi


/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-actions.sh: line 234: ${LISTOFPARTITIONS[$PARTTOUNFLAG}: bad substitution
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
SET@_progressbar1.pulse()
...
boot-repair basically hangs indefinitely after this
```

The `gui-action.sh` script line 234 looks like

```
PARTB=${LISTOFPARTITIONS[$PARTTOUNFLAG} #sdXY
```

Is this a known issue in boot-repair and if there is a workaround for this?

I'm curious is this maybe because I'm using nvme drive and nvme drives are labeled as `/dev/nvme0nXY` instead of `/dev/sdXY`. But I'm hoping that I'm not the first person who is trying to use boot-repair on the nvme drive.

Comment: At least a couple of years ago Boot-Repair was updated to include NVMe drives correctly. I have had NVMe drive for a while and Boot-Repair runs without issue. I just ran boot-repair-4ppa200  in my 22.04 Kubuntu install without issue. I have one NVMe and one SATA drive both with lots of partitions. What version of Boot-Repair? Boot-Repair tries to find & find data in partitions, but if corrupted it may hang and that is not a boot issue, it can fix. Post this for all drives `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` and any SATA drives also.

Comment: ... I don't even see a `/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-actions.sh` file in the version currently in the Focal repo (boot-repair_4ppa200_all.deb)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by changing the mentioned line (in `/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-actions.sh` line 234) to the following:

```
PARTB=${LISTOFPARTITIONS[$PARTTOUNFLAG]} #sdXY
```

The "]" was missing.